# Contents of java file in Eclipse Truncated

Tags: android, eclipse

After my Laptop abnormally shutdown due to charging issue, I lost all contents of my Import.java file. Though I saved my file 30 sec before PC shuts down. But after that when i open my laptop, that file is totally empty, though the java file in the PC is of 20KB.

I tried to open that java file with a notepad, and there are lots of spaces with no text.

Can I any way restore the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file in Eclipse and choose `Restore from Local History...`. Eclipse will show you the versions of the file that it has saved.  It may not have the very latest version but hopefully it will have something reasonably up to date.

Comment: seriously greg, I just can't tell u how grateful I am .. for last 20 mins everything was just darkening in my eyes and I was seriously paying for some miracles ... I lost thousands of codes before, not I restore most of them ... millions of salutes ...